# Actions On Google NodeJS v2 alpha: isRequestFromDialogflow function moved?

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm trying to migrate my cloud function from v1 to v2 (nodejs alpha), the command 'app.isRequestFromDialogflow()' no longer works, was this replaced with another function in the alpha version?

Error I'm getting:

```
TypeError: app.isRequestFromDialogflow is not a function
```

Do we no longer need to verify that the source of webhook requests is Dialogflow?

Edit: https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v2-auth-setup Ok, so it's handled automatically in v2?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

Now that the v2 library has been released, the `verification` property API is stable and now throws a [403 status by default](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/blob/be7fb67a666a9d8df435818fad9226118e6ca010/src/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.ts#L391) but is customizable. The reference docs for the verification field are [here](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/interfaces/dialogflow.dialogflowoptions.html#verification).

## Original Answer

In the v2 alpha (which functionality can change based on feedback), this is currently implemented with the [`verification`](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/blob/3088cda9d62498b417a1108e09398f754f8e1068/src/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.ts#L325) property in the options object when creating the cross conversational `app` instance by calling the `dialogflow` function.

Here's an example:

```es6
const app = dialogflow({
  verification: {
    HEADER_KEY: 'HEADER_VALUE',
  },
})
```

The `verification` property accepts a [JavaScript object](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/blob/3088cda9d62498b417a1108e09398f754f8e1068/src/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.ts#L317) with the keys being the Header keys and the values being the Header values to verify it comes from Dialogflow which you had set in the Dialogflow Console Webhook Fulfillment page.

The page [you linked](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v2-auth-setup) is about authentication for the general Dialogflow v2 API, not the webhook fulfillment. That's for if you want to get or manipulate the configured intents and entities in Dialogflow itself not to fulfill a user request.

Comment: Cool, how would this react to an invalid header key being provided? Currently my 'app.isRequestFromDialogflow' check returns a 400 error upon failure, would this new app instance verification handle the failure gracefully? Or will I need to specify the behaviour for such a scenario (like the current return 400 error method)?

Comment: Right now it will [throw a regular Error](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/blob/3088cda9d62498b417a1108e09398f754f8e1068/src/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.ts#L416) which will propagate up to Express and [send a 500 error](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/blob/3088cda9d62498b417a1108e09398f754f8e1068/src/framework/express.ts#L37) by default. The behavior does seem to make more sense to be a 400 level error like a 403. We'll track this so the behavior makes more sense and maybe customizable.