# Verify request fullfilment dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm trying to verify our fulfillment cloud function is only requested by Dialogflow.

The recommended solution is "[Verifying requests](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/webhook/reference/verify-requests)" but, in our case, we are using Dialogflow, not Actions SDK:

```
const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google');

const fulfillment = dialogflow({
    clientId: "clientIdDialogflow",
    debug: true,
    verification: "projectId"
});
fulfillment.intent("bienvenida",  (conv) => { commonsDialogController.wellcomeFunction(conv) });

...etc
```

1. Is it possible use this to verify a request in Dialogflow or only is available in Actions SDK?
2. If in Dialogflow, and it is not possible use this, we have to retrieve the header and to process JWT, but in the logs the authorization header is not present. The headers are:

   ```
   Headers { "host": "URL.cloudfunctions.net", "user-agent": "Google-Dialogflow", "transfer-encoding": "chunked", "accept": "*/*", "accept-encoding": "gzip,deflate,br", "content-type": "application/json", "forwarded": "for=\"X.X.X.X\";proto=https", "function-execution-id": "7868dfgr656", "x-appengine-country": "ZZ", "x-appengine-default-version-hostname": "aaaaa-tp.appspot.com", "x-appengine-https": "on", "x-appengine-request-log-id": "id", "x-appengine-user-ip": "X.X.X.X", "x-cloud-trace-context": aaaaaa/aaaa=1", "x-forwarded-for": "X.X.X.X", "x-forwarded-proto": "https", "connection": "close" }
   ```

   The error in the response is:

   ```
   { "status": 403, "body": { "error": "A verification header key was not found" }, "headers": { "content-type": "application/json;charset=utf-8" } }
   ```

Comment: To understand better: you have a DialogFlow fulfilment which needs to invoke the Action SDK? And you want to apply security (ensure the caller is DialogFlow)?

Comment: Yes, but in my fulfilment we are using dialogflow, not Action SDK. But we want to use this feature included in Action SDK: https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/webhook/reference/verify-requests

Answer (score 0):

check out this [answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49394831/actions-on-google-nodejs-v2-alpha-isrequestfromdialogflow-function-moved/49418586#49418586) regarding Dialogflow verification.

You can set verification headers on the Dialogflow console and verify it with the fulfillment library like so:

```es6
const app = dialogflow({
  verification: {
    HEADER_KEY: 'HEADER_VALUE',
  },
})
```

In the Dialogflow console, you can set the header key and value under `Fulfillment` > `Webhook` > `HEADERS`.